# AttributeError: 'ContactSerializer' object has no attribute 'get_status'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Hi all I have this error when im trying to save my serializer

```
AttributeError: 'ContactSerializer' object has no attribute 'get_status'
```

I render my serializer as form so I've created custom template for forms just to add new classes

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    status = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    name = serializers.CharField(
        style={
            "template": TEMPLATE_PATH,
            "class": "custom_form_control",
            "input_type": "input"
        }
    )

    email = serializers.CharField(
        style={
            "template": TEMPLATE_PATH,
            "class": "custom_form_control",
            "input_type": "input"
        }
    )

    subject = serializers.CharField(
        style={
            "template": TEMPLATE_PATH,
            "class": "custom_form_control",
            "input_type": "select",
            "choice": Contact.SUBJECT
        }
    )

    message = serializers.CharField(
        style={
            "template": TEMPLATE_PATH,
            "input_type": "textarea",
        }
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = "__all__"
```

And everything works great but when I'm trying to POST it (save it) i get attribute error.

My guess is that this is related to status field that is read-only and defaults to "New"

**models**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    APP = 'app support'
    PAY = 'payment support'
    HR = 'HR/Jobs'
    OTHER = 'other'
    SUBJECT = [
        (APP, _('App Support')),
        (PAY, _('Payment Support')),
        (HR, _('HR & Jobs')),
        (OTHER, _('Non related (Other)'))
    ]

    STATUS = (
       ('New', _('New')),
       ('In Progres', _('In Progres - somone is taking an action')),
       ('Resolved', _('Resolved - action was made')),
   )

    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=50, validators=[MinLengthValidator(4)])
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=55, blank=False)
    subject = models.CharField(choices=SUBJECT, max_length=15, blank=False)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, max_length=15, default=STATUS[0][0])

    def __str__(self):
        return str(f'{self.subject} is {self.status}')
```

**views**

```
class ContactAPIView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'contact.html'

    def get(self, request):

        serializer = ContactSerializer()
        return Response({'serializer': serializer})

    def post(self, request):

        serializer = ContactSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield), you need to specify a companion method called `get_fieldname` by default (if you're not providing a `method_name` argument). Also, `SerializerMethodField` is always read-only. So in your case it should be:

```py
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_status(self, obj):
        return obj.status
    ...
```